Does input tag always has to come right under form tag? or is nesting input on multiple levels under form tag valid?
I was looking into wrapping various input tags under form and I wonder how many nested elements are possible and not be semantically weird.
I've heard that there are semantic rules and some people mentioned about html semantics and why wrapping form is important.
Here div tag is not related to form but input is still under form so would this be semantically correct? would there be a problem?
<form>
   <div>
      <div>
         <input ... />
      </div>
   </div>
</form>


Both are semantically correct. What do you wish to know?

I think it is more semantically correct to use a div,
Because it is customary to use  on its own and not in nesting tags.

I was using input alone before then some people mentioned how it's semantically important to wrap it with form tag (same with ul ol li). Then I wondered how many nested elements can I put inside?
So is it ok to have any nested elements (div, span, input, label, ul, li, ...etc) inside form tag? or is there a limit to what can be included?
I know the code runs fine but i just wondered which is good practice to do or not to do^^

@KissMil Please focus on one exact question, not ask about five questions. Please [edit] your post to ask only one question. There is a difference between "what does the specification say/allow" and "what is good practice" (and the latter is off-topic here).

Sorry 'bout that I just edited the question. I just want to know if i'm not going against any html semantic rules by nesting input. So I guess @TowsifAhamedLabib is right then?

If you want to know if something is valid or allowed then you can simply use a Markup Validator.

Thanks guys~! @tacoshy I'll check that out~!~!

Yes, you can nest input elements within multiple levels of other elements (such as div, span, etc.) inside a form tag without violating HTML semantics. HTML5 specifications allow for such nesting as long as the nested elements are valid flow content. There is no strict limit on the level of nesting, but it should be used logically and accessibly to ensure good practice.
like
<form>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="text" name="username" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>

Using a table for layout purposes will solve your design needs but is semantically incorrect in modern HTML. Tables should be used only for tabular data, not for form layouts. Instead, your use of div elements and CSS for layout is semantically correct.
And as always, you can use https://validator.w3.org/ (Markup Validator) to check. (Sorry for taking it from comments, if you wish to add a separate answer, I'll remove it asap.)

taking information from comments to bundle information in an answer is absolutely fine. However, the answer could be improved. For once you should quote and reference documentations on such questions such as MDN WebDocs. Which clearly states: Permitted content: Flow content, but not containing <form> elements which means it is allowed every element with the exception of another form.

Last but not least, this is msotlikely not strictly tabular content and as such a table would be semantically speaking a wrong use. To bundle multiple , logical connected inputs and labels you should use fieldset

This is Great~!~! I'll still mark this answer acceptable since it answered my question and @tacoshy thanks~ for the additional informations~! I'll look into mdn flow content

Thanks @tacoshy, for the valuable inputs
